# How to get user position by GPS in Sencha

Tags: android, sencha-touch

I'm trying to get user position in Sencha Touch 2:

```
var geo = new Ext.util.Geolocation({
        autoUpdate: true,
        allowHighAccuracy: true,
        listeners: {
            locationupdate: function(geo) {
                lat = geo.getLatitude();
                lon = geo.getLongitude();

                // here comes processing the coordinates   
            }
        }
    });
```

But I've got coordinates only from network. There's no GPS icon on Android device, pointing that I'm using GPS. Also it doesn't work when I turn off internet connection. How can I enable GPS positioning? In Manifest file GPS is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got bit by this too.

It turns out there's a bug in Sencha: in [Ext.util.Geolocation.parseOption](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/source/Geolocation.html#Ext-util-Geolocation) they name the parameter `allowHighAccuracy` but [the w3c specs](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) name it `enableHighAccuracy`.
I added the following code to my application init to fix that:

```
var parseOptions = function() {
    var timeout = this.getTimeout(),
        ret = {
            maximumAge: this.getMaximumAge(),
            // Originally spells *allowHighAccurancy*
            enableHighAccuracy: this.getAllowHighAccuracy()
        };

    //Google doesn't like Infinity
    if (timeout !== Infinity) {
        ret.timeout = timeout;
    }
    return ret;
};
Ext.util.Geolocation.override('parseOptions', parseOptions);
```

For the record: the bug [has been reported over a year ago](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?130292-OPEN-TOUCH-137-enableHighAccuracy-allowHighAccuracy-in-GeoLocation), and `the fix was applied for TOUCH-2804 in a recent build`. I don't know what that means, but sure enough the bug is still in 2.0

EDIT: using the approach mentioned above doesn't work well either. The GPS icon would turn on and off as Exts calls getCurrentPosition repeatedly using a setInterval. The reason for doing this is that `The native watchPosition method is currently broken in iOS5`. In my Android targeted application I ended up ditching Ext:util.Geolocation and directely used navigator.geolocation.watchPosition. After that it worked like a charm.

Comment: Yeah, I've also eventually came to use Phonegap's navigator.geolocation.watchPosition

Comment: The bug has been fixed in 2.02 for enableHighAccuracy and is available for support subscribers, the next public release is 2.1

Answer (score 0):

GPS location provider determines location using satellites. Depending on conditions, this provider may take a while to return a location fix. 
Requires the permission **android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.**

Comment: Yes, this permission is added. But GPS is not used, and with turned off internet **locationupdate** isn't called at all.

Comment: Refer this link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/GeolocationPermissions.html and also http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

Comment: I need to access these features not in pure Java, but in Sencha framework.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think you need updated longitude and latitude values .

follow this link.. [Click Here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/android-location-based-services.html)

I already tried it and test it in android mobile phone.. Its working.

Note : Must and should test in android mobile phone with on GPS status. It will not show on eclipse emulator. But it will show in mobile phone try it..

have a nice.

Comment: Interesting information, but it's also for pure Java. I develop in Sencha framework, and I need to access GPS through this framework. In documentation they say that Ext.util.Geolocation automatically uses GPS, but I can't achieve that.