# geolocation.watchposition not working with network based location off

Tags: android, html, cordova, geolocation, gps

I am building a location aware app for Android using sencha 2.3.1 + phonegap 3.3.0, and use geolocation to  show a list of destinations ordered by proximity to the user location. 
Everything works fine if the setting for network-based location is on. But if I turn it off and leave gps only based location then it never gets detected.
The code is very basic, I tried both the sencha path:

```
Ext.device.Geolocation.watchPosition({
    frequency: 10000, 
    callback: function(position) {
      AppHelper.setCurrentLocation(position);//yeah!!

    },
    failure: function() {
        AppHelper.setLocationModeOff();//oouch!
    }
});
```

and the phonegap path:

```
var success = function(position) {
        AppHelper.setCurrentLocation(position);
    };
 var fail = function() {
            AppHelper.setLocationModeOff();
    };
   navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, fail,{ timeout: 30000 });
```

Result is the same, I tried waiting for a couple minutes for the geolock to happen but no sign of location service.

The phonegap location plugin is installed, the permissions are correct, and everything works if network location is enabled.

I am testing on a Sony Tablet S.

I am aware of this bug:
[How to get user position by GPS in Sencha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925289/how-to-get-user-position-by-gps-in-sencha/10837103#10837103)
But I checked the code and its is definetely fixed in sencha 2.3.1

I wil try on other devices but I was wondering if anybody experienced the same.

TIA.

EDIT: 
I made an experiment using standard html5 code on my android device using systems default browser (webkit based). 
I would access my settings page and change settings at each run.

Accessing http://html5demos.com/geo I get the following:

I started the device with network geolocation on and gps based location off:
I get a message that asks if I want to share my location I say yes, only this time everything works fine.

Turn off network based geolocation, gps still off:
Location detection fails. (as expected)

Turn on GPS, leave network geolocation off:
Geolocation fails silently, I don't get a request to use my location and subsequent activation of GPS based gelocation.

So my conclusion is: this is similar to what I noticed in phonegap. If network based geolocation is on everything works as expected. But if I have no network connection and gps is on that is pretty useless in my html5 app.

At least this is what happens on my device (sony tablet)

Comment: same problem with multiple devices...

Comment: have you installed the phonegap geolocaion plugin? if you haven't, then you're using the browser's html5 geolocation api, maybe it can explain this behaviour?

Comment: In his question, he states he has the geolocation plugin and the relevant permissions. What I would like to know is what happens when user gave access_to_coarse_location permission installing the app, then disables it through the device settings. I guess the disabling overrides in some way the permission given to the app at install time.

Comment: I expect the disabling to override the permissions. My interpretation is: the application level permission system grants access to a phone function unless that function is disabled on the phone at general settings level. Which is ok. My problem is that neither sencha nor phonegap seem to be very good at detecting changes in the general settings while the application is open, and the fall back to GPS only (no network based detection) seems not to work.

Comment: My point is that this fallback you expect has nothing to do with Sencha or Cordova/Phonegap, but should be implemented at HTML5 API level. We could setup a simple web app with geolocalization to prove this, no Sencha or Cordova/Phonegap involved, and see its behaviour.

Comment: That's a good idea. I think I can easily do that. Will do that over the weekend and let you know..

Comment: Both android and ios have native location managers which let you set up "significant location change" monitoring (eg. if user moves 100 meters, notify your app).  I have a Phonegap plugin which exposes these native APIs.  Would this be of any interest to you?

Comment: Ryan, the plugin you are talking about, is it an alternative to org.apache.cordova.geolocation ?

Comment: @RyanWheale I would be interested in such a plugin, where can we find it?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of HTML5 geolocation API, that is expected behaviour, you just can't control if under the hood it is using gps or network location.

What's probably happening is that `watchPosition()`, when it is called, tries first a raw, quick positioning using network, then goes with the gps positioning to give you a better result (assuming you called it with the enableHighAccuracy parameter).

If you are disabling network positioning it probably gets stuck at the first point: as stated in cordova/phonegap's docs the permission to access coarse location is a requirement for geolocation to work.

```
(in app/AndroidManifest.xml)

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I am guessing that revoking access to coarse location from the device settings somehow "overrides" the user permission given when installing the app.