# GPS position not working

Tags: javascript, android, gps, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am using Sencha 2.3. i want to show user's current position with high accuracy in android mobile. i apply below code.

```
Ext.create('Ext.util.Geolocation',
  autoUpdate: true,
  frequency:1000;
  allowHighAccuracy: true,
  listeners: { 
     locationupdate: function(geo) {
           latitude=geo.position.coords.latitude;
           longitude=geo.position.coords.longitude;
           if(Global.currentUserPositionMarker)
           {
              latlng1=new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
              currentPosMarker.setPosition(latlng1);
           }
        }
     }
   });
```

Problem is that it takes current position of mobile network provider not a GPS.
**When i turn on  WI-FI, It works fine using GPS** but to solve this problem i have to turn on WIFI that's not good solution. i want to get current position using only GPS without turn on WIFI.

Comment: Try did like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925289/how-to-get-user-position-by-gps-in-sencha. Hope i help you.

Comment: @FanFM  Which is already fixed in sencha touch 2.3.1